Wandb : Glob may not walk above the base path
I run a neural network and I want to use Wandb to track the metrics. Here is my code :
from wandb.keras import WandbCallback

wandb.init(project="my-project", name="my-run")
logs_dir = os.path.join(wandb.run.dir, "logs")
wandb.save(logs_dir)

*** many things ***

model.fit(
    train_X, train_Y,
    validation_data=(test_X, test_Y),
    epochs=20,
    batch_size=32,
    callbacks=[WandbCallback()]
)

As stated in the documentation : https://docs.wandb.ai/ref/python/integrations/keras/wandbcallback
However I get this error, coming from "callbacks=[WandbCallback()]" :
ValueError: Glob may not walk above the base path

Here is the code producing the error : https://github.com/wandb/wandb/blob/main/wandb/sdk/wandb_run.py
That's why in the beggining of the code I try to adapt the saving path. Whatever I can do I get this error. Anyone has an idea ?
Thanks

Update to latest Keras, wandb and try:
from wandb.integration.keras import WandbCallback

We recently updated the integration.

I upgraded both wandb and keras and I get the error : self.model = model
AttributeError: can't set attribute, see this post. Wandb seems to not work with latest keras version ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78284130/attributeerror-cant-set-attribute-model-with-wandbcallback-in-kaggle-keras
